# Create a checkBox for each item in a list in Nuke

Tags: python, checkbox, nuke

This is my problem :

I want to create a CheckBox for each node selected. I've managed to create the CheckBoxes for each node with the correct names but the problem is that where they are selected in the checkbox and print the result only return the first node selected or a boolean result (True or False), no matter what check box is selected. I can't find the answer.

Thanks for everything!

```
import nuke

nodeNames = [n.name() for n in nuke.allNodes('Write')]

names = []
for s in nuke.allNodes('Write'):
    n = s['name'].value()
    names.append(n)
#print names
#len(names)

writeNodes = ( ", ".join( str(e) for e in names ) )


p = nuke.Panel ('TEST')

for items in names:
    de = p.addBooleanCheckBox(items,'True')    

p.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create your own subclass of PythonPanel if you want to return information from the panel. Something like this:

```
class WritesPanel( nukescripts.PythonPanel ):
    def __init__( self , nodeNames):
        nukescripts.PythonPanel.__init__( self, "Write Nodes", "unique.panel.id" )

        self.nodeNames=nodeNames

        for nodeName in nodeNames:
            self.k = nuke.Boolean_Knob(nodeName, nodeName)

            self.addKnob( self.k )

    # The next function shows the dialog as a modal dialog. Doing this 
    # automatically adds the 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons to the dialog.

    def showModalDialog( self ):
        result = nukescripts.PythonPanel.showModalDialog( self )
        if result:
            results={}
            for nodeName in self.nodeNames:
                results[nodeName]=self.knobs()[nodeName].value()
            return results
        else:
            return None

# The following function calls WritesPanel

def launchWritesPanel(nodeNames):
    return WritesPanel(nodeNames).showModalDialog()
```

Call `launchWritesPanel` with your nodeNames list, and the panel will return a dictionary of `{nodeName:True/False}` if the user presses OK, or `None` if the user cancels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried creating the subclass, what I've got is this:  `NameError: name 'nodeNames'` is not defined. Don't know what Im doing wrong, by the way, this method keeps and return the names of the nodes in my list?